# Storage space of the phone

Tags: android, storage

I developed an application that has filled the storage of phone knowing that its size is only 600Ko.

this problem has happened during my tests in the emulator so that the solution was to increase the storage capacity of the emulator.

but now I test on my phone when space is at 169Mo/181Mo :s and I do not know how clear the memory knowing that I have no access to data/data

the second thing I do not know how to solve this problem in the application code.

### EDIT:

put a down mean nothing to me without comment!

if my English is bad is because I speak French

Comment: This question is impossible to answer in its current state - how do you expect others to debug your app without any detail such as the code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Response of Louis Semprini:

Thanks for posting this question. I have some additional insights that may help some developers.

I am debugging my application on a device (not the emulator). The device has 21MB free on /data (as revealed by "df" when doing "adb shell") and my app is only 5MB. However, I did find that if I deleted other apps on the device (without rebooting the phone or restarting adbd), INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE would go away for a while, then come back.

So seems that debugging my 5MB app requires more like 20MB of space in /data, and in addition something was leaking each time I debugged my app.

So I did "adb shell" and listed the ENTIRE /data directory with

```
cd /data
ls -a -l -R
```

and looked at the 5000-line output to see where all the space was going.

I discovered vast quantities of wasted space on my device in the /data/klog directory in the form of old log files from months-old debugging sessions.

These were not my log files: they were created by some part of the Android infrastructure.

I deleted them and instantly saved 58MB which was not attributed in the Settings app to any particular app. I have a small device so 58MB is very significant (about 40%).

So far, I have not gotten INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE again after many runs. Let's hope that was the real issue, though the OP suggests that his device had plenty of space (but didn't say how much).

Hopefully some of you will also be able to escape INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE by periodically deleting /data/klog/*

Or, you can at least do the `ls -a -l -R` in /data to see where all your space is going, if indeed there is really some (hidden) space issue.

### PS:

***and I invite those who have put down without comment to go to learn the right way communication***